# Limit access to Azure SQL Server to specific azure web apps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-server

Is it possible to allow access to azure sql server, only to specific azure web app.

If possible , then do we have to configure start and end IP address of web app in azure sql server in "Firewall and Virtual Network". Also how to find start and end IP address of azure web app ?

Answer (score 1):

There are **two types of IP addresses. Inbound and outbound**. For outbound IP, click properties . This will display a list of all possible outbound IP addresses.

[image]

For inbound IP address, click on Custom Domains from the properties menu and IP will appear there.

[image]

Comment: How to configure these Inbound and Outbound Ip address of Azure Web app in azure sql server in "Firewall and Virtual Network" ?

Comment: And Can we Limit the access to Azure SQL Server for Azure Web Apps using Inbound and Outbound IP addresses